# How can I add multiple buttons to the default Laravel Mail Notification

Tags: php, laravel, email

I've been using the laravel notifications for my mail. I have run `vendor --publish` and have my template which I've been using.
All my mails have either included a single button or none.
How do I handle a situation where I have 2 buttons?
I found this in the `email.blade.php`.

```
{{-- Action Button --}}
@isset($actionText)
<?php
    switch ($level) {
        case 'success':
            $color = 'green';
            break;
        case 'error':
            $color = 'red';
            break;
        default:
            $color = 'blue';
    }
?>
@component('mail::button', ['url' => $actionUrl, 'color' => $color])
{{ $actionText }}
@endcomponent
@endisset
```

Can I create a loop to check for multiple buttons? and what values do I use??